# Mensaje de Confirmación sweetAlert2 - Controlador de Laravel8

Tags: laravel, sweetalert2

Estoy usando un mensaje de Confirmación con SweetAlert2 desde un controlador de Laravel, ya que el se muestra si se cumple una condición,quisiera saber como hago para que al confirmar la acción (Botón-Registrar) el continue con la siguiente linea de código en el controlador.

```
if ($buscaPrenez->count()>0) {
    # Si exite calculamos los días transcurridos de gestación.
    $tgc = Carbon::parse($request->fecharegistro)->diffInDays($fep);//Tiempo de Gestación Trasncurridos
               
    if ($tgc < $tgesta) {
                **#Se envía el mensaje**
                return back()->with('prue', 'pnc');
**#Al aceptar o confirmar el mensaje que continue aqui**
                return "Si Continua";
                # 1.- Creamos el registro de preñez no concluuida

                # Creamos la preñez nueva  
                #return back()->with('info', 'ok');  
                }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En mi opinión, creo que eso debes manejarlo con Javascript o lo que sea que uses en el front, primero deberías crear un `endpoint` para para verificar si "existe", luego continuar con el registro con otro endpoint. No sé si se entienda.

Comment: Realmente, pudo resolverlo usando Ajax.